# Set real time decimal format to JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, integer, dialog, joptionpane

I have a `JFormattedTextField` that have a decimal format and if the value is lower or equal 0 it shows a `showInputDialog` to update it.

How can I set a 'real time' decimal formatter for `showInputDialog`?

```
// Format
NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


// Text field
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField();


// Validation
String regex = "[.,]";
String valueString = textField.getText().split(",")[0].replaceAll(regex, "");
int value = (int) Double.parseDouble(valueString);

while(value <= 0) {
    value = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parentComponent, "The value must be greater than 0", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE));
}
```

I can't figure out how can I do it.

Comment: Where do you tell the `JFormattedTextField` your `NumberFormat`?  You'll get better help if you include a compilable, runnable [mre] with your question.

Comment: What is a "real time decimal formatter"? I have never heard that definition.

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormatter (or MaskFormatter) is probably what you are looking for.

```
NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format); //also check MaskFormatter 
formatter.setValueClass(Integer.class);
formatter.setMinimum(0);
formatter.setMaximum(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);

// value is be committed on each keystroke instead of focus lost
    formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
    
 JFormattedTextField textField  = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the value can be retrieved with `int value = ((Number) textField.getValue()).intValue();`.